# Reactjs componentDidMount with dataread when no values

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have a reactjs application talking to Mogodb-Atlas.
when I am reading some times there is no data in the db and it is crashing.

As I have to show thhe data in the UI (in render) I am doing the reading in the componentdidmont

```
componentDidMount = async (event) => {
        const { theId } = this.props
        const { mongodb } = this.props;
        await mongodb.db("MasterDB")
            .collection("ReadyTable")
            .find({"theId":Id,"Flag":"Ready"})
            .asArray()
            .then(ReadyTable => {
                this.setState({ ReadyTable });
                this.setState({ toprocessID: ReadyTable[0].toprocessID });
                }
                });
```

This code works if there is entry in that table with Ready.
sometimes that table is not updated and than this crashes.
is there a way I can make sure it does not crash.
As there is no data it crashesas I am assigning that data

Comment: What is the `mongodb` prop?  And why are you trying to communicate directly with your DB from your front end?

Comment: how do you suggest to communicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a condition to render function before using **ReadyTable** array. It maybe helps you. Here is an example of the same.

```
render() {
  const { ReadyTable } = this.state;
  return(
     ReadyTable.length > 0 && 
      // other stuff that you want show
  )
}
```